# Why are "sugar" and "sure" pronounced with an SH?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, pronunciation-vs-spelling, palatalization

As far as I know, those are the only two.  They should be pronounced *Soogher* and *Soor*, shouldn't they?  I looked them up on Dictionary.com, and their etymologies reveal no trace of an *SH*, except where the listing for *sugar* had:

> Middle English sugre, sucre (noun) < Middle French sucre  < Medieval Latin succārum  < Italian zucchero  < Arabic sukkar;  obscurely akin to Persian shakar, Greek sákcharon

I see an obscure kinship to *shakar*, but the word morphed so many times since then that the *SH* disappeared pretty much completely.  And *sure* is even worse, with no sign of *SH*:

> Middle English sur ( e ) < Middle French sur, Old French seur  < Latin sēcūrus

Why are these the only two like this?

Comment: We get those later two words in English a bit more directly as `shaker` (small spice dispenser, typically for salt or pepper) and `saccharine` (overly sweet).

Comment: Could this be [palatalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization) or something similar? I'm pretty sure there's a posh British pronunciation of "sure" as `/ʃjʊə(r)/` ("syoor") but I can't find any references.

Comment: It is quite clear that in general, over time, 'su' has come to be pronounced as '-shu', perhaps from an Arabic origin but not confirmed to my knowledge. It is an interesting observation however, showing existence of different pronunciations for different letter combinations, in English, similar to French or Spanish.

Comment: also pressure, fissure, commissure, etc.; and sumac (in some dialects).

Comment: This reminds me of the story recounted on [QI](http://www.qi.com/); The lecturer asserted `Sugar is the only word in the english language where the 'su' is pronounced 'Sh'` A student replied, `Are you sure?`

Comment: @T.E.D.: I always thought "shaker" just came from the verb "to shake," and I can't find any reference that disagrees with that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-sug1.htm) interesting page explains that *sugar* used to be pronounced originally with a common *su* sound, but (emphases mine):

> (...) sometime in the Middle English
>   period the initial letters su shifted
>   to the pronunciation they now have.
>
> If you relax the mouth and tongue
>   somewhat when you are saying the older
>   form, your pronunciation shifts to the
>   modern one, as you’ll realise if you
>   try out the two sounds in turn; the
>   modern version is actually rather
>   easier for slack-jawed English
>   speakers to say. (...)
>   **The same change happened with other words, such as *sure***, and also to words in which
>   the sound occurred in the middle, such as *pressure* and *nation*. By the time this shift in
>   pronunciation was taking place, the spelling of the words had already become fixed (...)

Comment: Any phonetics discussion that says things like "relax the mouth and tongue" and "easier for slack-jawed English speakers" is, frankly, highly dubious. There is no scientific phonetic support for arguments like that.

Comment: I just heard "dishused" (yes, with an sh sound).  And look at "groceries", many pronounce that as "grosheries" (or maybe just Americans?  The "dishused" came from a Brit I'm pretty sure).  I do have to admit that I'm not a linguist, and thus do not have *all* the scientific literature memorized…

Answer (score 21):

The sound of French /u/ (a [close front rounded vowel](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ea/Close_front_rounded_vowel.ogg)) is denoted [y]. *Sugar* is from French *sucre* [sykʀ(ə)], and *sure* is from French *sur* (*e*) [syːʀ].

Middle English kept that vowel originally—as [sykrə] and [syːr(ə)], respectively—but over time it was transformed into [ju] (like modern *you*). What was previously [sy-] thus became [sju-] ([RP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Received_Pronunciation) *sue*) and eventually [ʃʊ-] (as in modern *sugar*).

This happened in other contexts: *-tion* is pronounced [-sjɔ̃] in French, with a nasal vowel. This became [-sjɔn] (*syon*) or [-sjən] (*syun*), and finally [-ʃən] (*shun*).

Answer (score 6):

As you say, there doesn't seem to be any way the pronunciation of "s" as "sh" in *sugar* (and *sure*) could be related to the “sh” in Persian *shakar.* Rather, it seems to have developed (apparently irregularly) within English.

### Palatalization of /sj/ to /ʃ/, which could also occur in other words historically

The use of the “sh” sound (in IPA, /ʃ/) in *sugar* and *sure* developed after they had entered English, via palatalization of the sound /s/ before the palatal glide /j/ (like “y” in “you”). As [Jon Purdy](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33456/77227) explains, these words developed a palatal glide due to the change from the French vowel /y/ (spelled "u") to English /juː/.

The sound /ʃ/ occurs for the same reason in many other words related to  *sure,* such as *surety* and *assure, ensure* etc. An analogous change affected the voiced counterpart of /s/, /z/, causing /zj/ to develop in many words to /ʒ/ (the sound at the start of the French name *Jacques*).

I found a good [Quora post by Uri Granta](https://www.quora.com/What-words-start-with-su-and-have-sh-sound-other-than-sugar-and-sure) that mentions a third word starting with the letter “s” that is pronounced by modern English speakers with the sound “sh” somewhat often: ***[sumac](http://www.onelook.com/?w=sumac&ls=a)***. However, modern dictionaries also list a pronunciation with /s/ for this word, so it is not as categorical as the other two words. (In fact, the book *[The Pronunciation of Standard English in America](https://books.google.com/books?id=7mB5AAAAIAAJ&q=sumac#v=onepage&q=sumach&f=false),*
by George Philip Krapp (1919), calls [ˈʃuːmæk] for *sumach* [sic] a dialectal pronunciation (p 124), and says it is not standard.)

Granta explains:

> **Sugar**, **sure** and **sumac** are the only three in Modern English, but
>   historically there were others. In the sixteenth century a phonetic
>   change of sy- to sh- was attested (in the shape of sh- misspellings)
>   not just in the words *sugar* and *sure,* but also in words like *suit*
>   (variously spelled shute, shutte, shuite and shuett), *suet* (spelled
>   showitt, shewet and shuet) and *sue* (spelled shue). By the nineteenth
>   century, the sy- pronunciations won out for all but *sugar, sure* and
>   *sumac* (and was later replaced by plain old s-), though the sh-
>   pronunciation also survived in the middle of some words like *issue,
>   tissue, assure, ensure, insure, pressure,* etc.

Another source I found that describes some of the history of this pronunciation is *[English Pronunciation in the Eighteenth Century: Thomas Spence's ‘Grand Repository of the English Language’](https://books.google.com/books?id=dfYBKFjf-2cC&pg=PA144&lpg=PA144&dq=yod%20coalescence%20English%20sugar%20sure&source=bl&ots=_yiSVuvOMg&sig=3K20ULgDGG8jlzxvDLMnx0cx4pU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjK1cCgmvHOAhUBEWMKHcgvBWoQ6AEIYjAJ#v=onepage&q=yod%20coalescence%20English%20sugar%20sure&f=false),* by Joan C. Beal (1999). According to Beal,

> much of the seventeenth-century evidence for the palatalization of
>   preceding alveolar consonants [...] is from ‘vulgar’ or dialectal
>   sources: Cooper, for instance, in his semi-phonetic notation, lists
>   *shugar* with the [j] assimilated, as a ‘barbarous’ pronunciation. By
>   the end of the eighteenth century, this palatalization, with its
>   subsequent assimilation of the /j/, is accepted even by Walker in
>   *sugar* and with palatalization but not assimilation in *sure,* but
>   elsewhere it is heavily stigmatized, at least in stressed syllables.
>   (144)

Some dictionary authors, such as Sheridan, did list pronunciations with word-initial /ʃ/ for some other words, but these pronunciations were criticized by other orthoëpists:

> We have already seen that the author of *A Caution to Gentlemen Who
>   Use Sheridan’s Dictionary* attacked Sheridan for his palatalizations
>   and, in our discussion of the words in Appendix 6*a*, that Sheridan had
>   more instances of palatalization than Spence or Burn before the
>   unstressed ⟨ure⟩ ending. It is certainly the case that Sheridan
>   admitted this palatalization of alveolars before earlier /juː/ to an
>   extreme degree: he has **palatalization of /s/ to /ʃ/ with consequent
>   loss of following /j/ in all words with the prefix *super-,*** whereas
>   Spence,  Walker and Burn all have /sjuː/ here, and in all similar
>   words except *sugar, sure* and *surety,* in which /ʃ/ occurs in PDE. (150)

Interestingly, Beal considers it possible that this palatalization was a feature of Irish English (which would support the relevance of [redbmk's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/33441/77227)):

> The author of *A Caution* and, indeed, Jespersen (1909-49: 344, 347)
>   attribute Sheridan’s pronunciation of words such as *tune* and *suicide*
>   to interference from Irish English. In many cases, the accusation of
>   ‘Irishism’ is a knee-jerk reaction from critics who simply did not
>   agree with Sheridan’s recommendations, but, in this case, there may be
>   some substance to it. Jespersen (1909-49: 347) points out that ‘B Shaw
>   writes *Choosda* and *schoopid* as Irish for *Tuesday* and *stupid* (John
>   Bull’s Isl. 12, 38)’. On the other hand, initial /tʃ/ and /ʃ/ for
>   /tj/ and /sj/ are attested in seventeenth century English (as opposed
>   to Irish) sources: Dobson (1957: 706-7) shows *suit: Shute: shoot* as
>   homophones in Hodges; and *tulip: julip* as well as *dew: due: jew* in
>   Brown (none of our sources shows initial /dj/ becoming /dʒ/). These
>   instances are, however, few and far between and in homophone lists,
>   which, as Dobson explains, often give more colloquial pronunciations.
>   If Sheridan’s palatalizations in *supreme, tune* etc. are not Irishisms,
>   perhaps they represent a more colloquial kind of London English.
>   (150-151)

However, she thinks it is more likely that these variants arose in London:

> I am informed (Karen Corrigan, personal communication) that this
>   palatalization does occur in Irish, but only in the Ulster dialects,
>   so that it is very unlikely that the Dublin-born Sheridan would have
>   been influenced by it. What is more likely is that the palatalization
>   was a colloquialism common in London, which may have been widely used
>   in less careful speech, then as now. (150-151, note 33)

I'm not sure precisely what she means by "then as now." I have heard that some, perhaps even many, present-day British English speakers merge /tj/ into /tʃ/ (i.e. their "tune" sounds like "choon") and /dj/ into /dʒ/, but I haven't heard of any that have /ʃ/ where standard British English has /sj/ or /s/.

### It's unclear why these words in particular show this change, and others don't in present-day English

I don't know of any explanation for why *sugar* and *sure* (and for some people *sumac*) ended up being pronounced with /ʃ/, but other words starting with ⟨su⟩ (such as *suit* and *super*) ended up being pronounced with /s/ by modern speakers.

### Example words showing the variable outcomes of historical /sjuː/ and /zjuː/ in present-day English

Before a stressed syllable:

- /s(j)/ or /z(j)/: 
          **sui**t, a**ssu**me, (resume, presume etc.) **su**preme, **su**ture, e**xu**de, e**xu**berant, e**su**rient. I found a number of other words like these, many of them words starting with *super-.*
- /ʃ/ or /ʒ/:
          **su**gar, **su**re (surety, assure, ensure etc.), **su**mac (pronunciations with /ʃ/ and /s/ both exist), lu**xu**rious, lu**xu**riant (these last 2 might have been influenced by *luxury*, which is stressed earlier), u**su**rious ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usurious) lists pronunciation with /z/ also; influence from *usury* seems plausible), cae**su**ra ([MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/caesura) lists pronunciation with /z/ also). I don't know of any other words like these.

Before an unstressed syllable:

- /ʃ/ or /ʒ/: pre**ssu**re, fi**ssu**re, sei**zu**re, trea**su**re, enclo**su**re, expo**su**re, u**su**ry, cen**su**re, ton**su**re, licen**su**re, a**zu**re, sen**su**al, sen**su**ous, se**xu**al, fle**xu**ous. I found a number of other words like these, many of them nouns with the suffix *-ure.*
- /s(j)/: in**su**late, in**su**lar, penin**su**la, in**su**lin, con**su**late, con**su**lar, cap**su**le, encap**su**late, Ur**su**la. There are a few more words I've found like these.
- variation between /s(j)/ and /ʃ/ and/or /z(j)/ and /ʒ/: e**xu**date, e**xu**dation, lapis la**zu**li, men**su**rable, men**su**ral, commen**su**rate.

Comment: Before an unstressed syllable, /ʃ/ or /ʒ/ seem to be the rule after a vowel, at least from your small set of examples.

Comment: @PeterShor: That might be a relevant factor. Oddly, another pattern (can't tell if it's causal or coincidental) is that for pretty much all of the words with /s(j)/ before an unstressed syllable, it comes before ⟨ul⟩. One word that I left out because it's rare and has an unusual spelling is "grossular." The dictionaries I've checked all say it is pronounced with /sj/; no pronunciations with coalescence or cluster simplification are listed. Another similar word seems to be "crassulaceous."

Answer (score 5):

The first part of 'sugar' used to be pronounced more like ''sue''. The vowel in that syllable is a high, back vowel and sometimes consonants change to be more like the vowels that are near them. It's called [assimilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_%28linguistics%29).

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed many Scottish and Irish Gaelic words to be spelled with an *s*, followed by a vowel, and pronounced like **sh**. Think about the way Sean Connery speaks (not to mention how the *Se* in his name is pronounced).

Read the section on nomenclature [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Gaelic#Nomenclature) and click on some of the links about Anglic and Scots (Yes, I realize I'm quoting Wikipedia, but there is a source attached to this quote). Note how the *s* is pronounced *sh*:

> Prior to the 15th century, the Anglic
>   speech of the Lowlands was known as
>   Inglis ("English"), with Gaelic being
>   called Scottis ("Scottish"). From the
>   late 15th century, however, it became
>   increasingly common to refer to
>   Scottish Gaelic as Erse ("Irish") and
>   the Lowland vernacular as Scottis.

There is also some good information about Scottish Gaelic [orthography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Gaelic_orthography) and [phonology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_Gaelic_phonology) that you might find useful if you can read IPA.

Comment: -1 Though this is an interesting answer, Celtic languages don't actually have to do with the pronunciations of the words in question.

Comment: Except that many patterns of sound change are common across all languages.