# The strange pronunciations of "assume"

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, yod-coalescence

Just a curious question:
Why is *"assume"* pronounced so funny by many native speakers?
I can't think of any other word where "ss" is pronounced like that.

A bit hard to explain via text, but it's like "sh" with something like a speech impediment.
You probably know what I mean.
Is there even a phoneme for this?

Comment: Do you mean the [**affectation**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/affectation) used by some notable people (for example the late Tony Benn and Sean Connery) of pronouncing it as **ashume**?

Comment: An "sh" sound similar to that in *assure*?

Comment: Perhaps some people articulate the vowel after SH more as a diphthong (the way Brits say TUES-day, where many Americans say TWOS-day). Is there any US/UK difference in prevalence for the feature being queried?

Comment: This is simple assimilation

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, lots of Americans pronounce it *assoom* /əˈsuːm/, but some pronounce it *asjoom* /əˈsjuːm/. It's possible the "strange pronunciation" is the second possibility, which is the standard British pronunciation.

Comment: Yes, I guess it's mostly British or Australian speakers, but they do not use the "second possibility" (*asjoom*), but indeed something similar to *"assure"* - as mentioned by @nnnnnn - but with an additional I or J. Probably need to rewatch some Bond movies.

Comment: @PeterShor: But I think even the most "adenoidally challenged" of your compatriots enunciate essentially the same diphthong in, say, VIEW-ers (that one's never VOO-ers), so it's not like they've got a problem moving the mouth and tongue around for that one. I can't easily tell the difference between "physically difficult" to articulate and *unfamiliar / awkward*, but I suspect it might be objectively more demanding to articulate this diphthong after "sibiliant" consonants.

Comment: (...and of course, in your specialist area, it's always KEW-bits, never COO-bits! :)

Comment: Hmmm, deja-vue, or rather deja-entendue with that name!
Try to pronounce these correctly! ;-)

Comment: @PeterShor These sites are a qbit strange. My advanced theoretical physics questions are generally butchered by a guy working in business software or other wannabes, while a simple English musing attracts top notch M.I.T. professors.

Comment: Do you mean a “sh” sound like that in *assure* and *passion*?

Comment: Could you add an audio/video example of someone pronouncing it like that? Maybe like [this](https://youglish.com/getbyid/23780819/assume/english/aus) or [this](https://youglish.com/getbyid/4569722/assume/english/aus) on YouGlish? I also checked [Forvo](https://forvo.com/word/assume/#en) but none of them had an "sh" sound.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Do you know what 'affectation' means? It is a perfectly normal variant of the standard British pronunciation [əˈsjuːm]; there is nothing affected about it.

Comment: "You probably know what I mean." No, I have no idea what you mean, and you haven't explained anything.

Comment: @non-user38741 Don't be rude. It's your question and therefore your responsibility to clearly explain what you're asking about. You can't assume other people can read your mind and know what you're thinking about! I've never heard anyone from any English dialect say *assume* "like a speech impediment".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Brief answer

*A**sy**oom* is sometimes pronounced *ASHOOM* in some accents because there's a tendency to [assimilate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilation_(phonology)) (coalesce) ‹S› with the following ‹Y› to a ‹SH› sound. The same thing happens in *bless you* when pronounced quickly. Another common example is *whatcha* (what + you).

### Explanation

'Assimilation' is what causes all these changes. It's a process which makes nearby sounds more similar (opposite: [*dissimilation* e.g. *colonel* pronounced *kernel*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/541188/365490)).

There are *place assimilation, voicing assimilation* and *assimilation of manner*.

- In **assimilation of place**, one of two adjacent sounds changes its place of articulation in order to make it more similar to the other sound, for example, *ten pies* is usually pronounced *te[**m**]pies* in fast (sometimes normal) speech (the place of articulation of the *n* changes).
- In **voicing assimilation**, one of the two adjacent sounds changes its voicing. For example, [the B in *absor**b*** changes to a P when the suffix *-tion* is appended](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/59538/365490): *absor**p**tion*.
- In **assimilation of manner**, one sound changes its manner of articulation to become similar in manner to a neighbouring sound. For example, *that side* is sometimes pronounced [ðæs saɪd]; the plosive /t/ changes its manner of articulation and becomes a fricative.

#### Pronunciation of *ASSUME* as *ASHOOM*

It's an example of *coalescent assimilation*. In this type of assimilation, two adjacent sounds are merged/[coalesced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-coalescence) to form a new sound. The following sounds often merge and make new sounds:

- **[s] + [j] → [ʃ]:** *Mi**ssio**n*, *a**ssu**re*, *se**xu**al* etc
- **[z] + [j] → [ʒ]:** *Vi**sio**n*, *trea**su**re*, *u**su**al*, *a**zu**re* etc
- **[t] + [j] → [t͡ʃ]:** *be**t y**ou* (*betcha*), *wha**t y**ou* (*whatcha*) etc
- **[d] + [j] → [d͡ʒ]:** *di**d y**ou* (*didja*), *woul**d y**ou* etc

*Assume* is pronounced [əˈsjuːm] in most British and Australian accents. If you check [dictionaries](https://www.onelook.com/?w=assume&ls=a), you will find [əˈ**sj**uːm] for British and [əˈ**s**uːm] (without the /j/) for American pronunciation<sup>**1**</sup> (therefore it may not be common in American accents). However, some people—mostly British and Australians—assimilate the [s] with the following [j] and pronounce it something like **[əˈʃuːm]**.

There are lots of other interesting examples—mostly historical—that illustrate the process. Some of them are:

- The prefix in the word *impossible* is *in-* but has been assimilated to an *m* because of the following /p/. *N* often assimilates to /m/ before /p m b/ etc
- Most people (including me) pronounce the *and* in *'bread and butter'* and *'bits and bobs'* as if it were an *m* in anticipation of the following sound

  - *bread[ə**m**]butter*
  - *bits[ə**m**]bobs*
- *Bless you* being pronounced with [ʃ]
- *Tune* is usually pronounced [t͡ʃuːn] (*CHOON*) in most varieties of British English
- [*Sure* and *sugar*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/346535/365490)
- Some people pronounce *handbag* [ˈhæ**m**bæɡ]: the first process involved in this case is simply the elision of the [d] and then the assimilation of *n* and *b* to *m*.
- *Have to* pronounced *hafta*

---

<sub>/s/ is the 's' in ***s**in*

/j/ the 'y' sound in ***y**ou*

/ʃ/ is the 'sh' in ***sh**ip*.

/ʒ/ in ***g**enre*

/t͡ʃ/ in ***ch**urch*.

/d͡ʒ/ in ***j**udge*.</sub>

<sup>**1:** "[In many accents of English, /sj/ at the start of a syllable has been simplified to /s/. This simplification has progressed further in North American English than in British English](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/546774/365490)"</sup>

Comment: The one that nails it for me is ***Bless you!*** Which until I read this I was blissfully unaware that I would *always* "assimilate" down to ***/ʃ/*** (the mouth knows what it's doing, even if the brain doesn't! :)

Comment: The /sj/ to [ʃ] is probably quite old: Norwegian Language Blog https://blogs.transparent.com/norwegian/sj-vs-kj/ *The “sj” sound is almost (but not quite exactly) the same as the English “sh” sound.  [...] the Norwegian “sj” seems to be a softer sound than the English “sh.”-- ”SJ”:  sjokk (shock), sjelden (seldom) ,sjalu (jealous), sjanse (chance), sjuk (sick), sjåvinisme (chauvinism) Notice the cognates and the different ways the same words start in English (ch, j, sh)-*

Comment: *Assume* is pronounced [əˈsuːm] in General American English, not [əˈsjuːm]. IIRC, GAE is more likely to drop yods where other dialects coalesce them.

Comment: I agree a native BrE speaker pronounces [t͡ʃuːn], but claiming that sounds like *CHOON* is completely wrong. The *ch* pronunciation sounds like a joke version of some (probably poorly educated) minority group's pronunciation - in the same not-really-funny category as things like "soshul meeja or "lora norda".

Comment: @alephzero: I wrote CHOON for those who don't understand IPA. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a Brit, I would never ever say [əˈsuːm]. This is strictly a North American pronunciation. I would say [əˈsjuːm] in careful speech, but this may well become [əˈʃuːm] in rapid speech. There is nothing strange about this.